# What is an interrupt in reverse called?

Tags: linux-kernel, network-programming, device-driver

So an *interrupt* is electronic signal generated by a hardware device and sent to the kernel to get the processors attention. But what is the term for an electronic signal generated by the kernel to instruct the device to do something? For example, network drivers have functions like **hard_start_xmit** and **netif_tx**. Now is it correct that many network adapters have their own instruction sets and when the device is started up these instructions are read by the kernel and loaded into memory. So to transmit a packet the kernel sends an electronic signal to the network adapter which is essentially an instruction to began transmitting packets loaded onto the devices memory buffer and before that the queued packets are bussed to the memory buffer before they are sent out. If this isn't correct then just exactly how does the kernel "tell" the device(the actual low level code) to began transmitting the data on queue?

Comment: So Sam, what you're saying is that the PCI bus has a section for control signals in addition to data and the Kernel buses the transmit instruction to the device instruction register. Amirite?

Comment: Moved all my comments and answer to your last question to real answer, it's more convenient this way.

Answer (score 2):

How kernel is "talking" to device -- strictly depends on device hardware interface. But in most cases such interaction is done via device [registers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_register) (you can read register value and write to register). How exactly kernel writes to registers of device -- depends on the way of how the device connected to CPU. If device is connected to CPU memory bus -- kernel can just write into corresponding register address on bus (in the same way how it's done for regular RAM). If device connected via some bus like [I2C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2C) or [PCI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conventional_PCI)  -- kernel talks to device using that bus protocol.

If you are talking about sending interrupt from CPU to some external device (which is also usually has some sort of CPU in it) -- it's usually done via [GPIO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General-purpose_input/output) line, configured for output.

In case of network adapters (which are using functions you mentioned), it is most likely that they are connected to CPU by PCI bus. In PC you have dedicated controller that handles PCI bus, called South bridge. Look at [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bd/Motherboard_diagram.svg) picture to get some clue. To figure out internals of PCI bus (i.e. how CPU sends electrical signals to devices) -- you can read [article on PCI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conventional_PCI) on wikipedia.

Regarding question about how transmission can be started on PCI Ethernet card. As per my understanding, you have 2 mechanisms to deal with device registers on PCI bus: [MMIO and PMIO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_I/O). First is just mapping PCI device addresses to RAM bus, second uses Port I/O bus (available on x86). Those two spaces are called [BARs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_configuration_space#Bus_enumeration). When you want to start transmission, you are usually writing some value to some (defined in device datasheet) register. To map PCI addresses to memory bus, one can use [pci_iomap()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/lib/pci_iomap.c#L54) function in kernel, which returns virtual address to beginning of mapped region. Once you have your PCI device mapped, you can use regular functions, like `iowrite32()` and so on, to read/write to register.

For example see [Realtek 8139](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/net/ethernet/realtek/8139too.c) driver:

- [rtl8139_init_board()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/net/ethernet/realtek/8139too.c#L754) function, which is mapping PCI device addresses to memory bus [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/net/ethernet/realtek/8139too.c#L821)
- [rtl8139_start_xmit()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/net/ethernet/realtek/8139too.c#L1717) function, which is starting transmission by doing [RTL_W32_F (TxStatus0 + ...)](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/net/ethernet/realtek/8139too.c#L1748) , which is in turn just `iowrite32()` operation